# Sending enter key on pop-up windows with batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, default, reset, sendkeys

I am writing a command line to run on batch file
`RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ResetIEtoDefaults` and wanted to make it click on the **reset** button automatically
I tried to use `-c "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.SendKeys('{left}') $wshell.SendKeys('{enter}')` but it didn't send the command to the pop-up windows, do you guys have any comments or inouts about this?

Comment: You would probably need to set the Window focus to the Control Panel Window as well.

Comment: believe @Squashman is right as it's just sending `enter` to the process and not the window it appears.  Is this within Powershell?

Comment: No, it's just a regular cmd